# Can't access Mongo db using Meteor-Blaze

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Using this code in a file "reports.js" in the same folder of "reports.html", I get 0 elements in the array returned. Not sure I am missing any extra declaration but also I can't use "import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';" without having error "Use of reserved word 'import'".
Meteor version 1.2.1

**JS**

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.reports.rendered = function(){
        if(Session.get("animateChild")){

            $(".reports-page").addClass("ng-enter");

            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".reports-page").addClass("ng-enter-active");
            }, 300);

            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".reports-page").removeClass("ng-enter");
                $(".reports-page").removeClass("ng-enter-active");
            }, 600);
        }
    };
}

Template.dashboardd.helpers({
  options() {
    return Tasks.find({});
  },
});
```

**HTML**

```
<Template name="dashboardd">
  {{#each options}}
    <p><label>{{text}}</label></p>
  {{/each}}
</Template>
```

Comment: I think you need to include babel or ecmascript packageto make the import work. Have you published and subscribed to the tasks collection?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK meteor 1.2 don't supports Imports. Improrts are new module added i meteor 1.3 or 1.4 im not sure.
I allways use this 3 Elements when work with collections (4 if we take collection declaration)

You should do on server side some publish and allows like:

```
Meteor.publish("Tasks ", function (selector, options) {
//you can remove condition if you dont have accounts-package
   if (this.userId) {
    return Tasks .find(selector || {}, options || {});
   }
});
```

And some Allows
    Once again if you dont have Meteor-accounts you can simply - return true, on inserts, updates etc. But I don't must say that is not safety :P

```
Tasks.allow({
 insert: function (userId, doc) {
return userId;
},

 update: function (userId, doc) {
    return userId;
 },

 remove: function (userId) {
  return userId;
 },
});
```

On Client side some subscribe

```
Template.YourTemplateName.onCreated(function () {
 this.autorun(() => {

    this.subscribe('Tasks', { _id: Template.currentData()._id });
 //or
   this.subscribe('Tasks');
 //but this solution can kill Browser when you collection will have a thousand elements. Allways try to not subscribe all collection. Only Needed fields/objects
  });
});
```